# how to detect for loop block after Parsing the code using Antlr?

Tags: java, c++, loops, antlr, antlr4

I am working with Antlr4 and I want to parse and analyze any c++ code to detect any loops in any c++ source code to do dependency analysis on them, I want to detect the outer loop and if it has inner loop I want to detect it as an inner loop,  but I can't detect any loop in the source code.

**What I have done and tried:**

This is the rule that I used for "for loops" in Antlr:

```
forBlock: 'for' '(' (classicFor | forEach) ')' controlStructureBody ;
forExpression: primaryExpression (',' primaryExpression)* ;
```

I print out the tokens in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            cout << i << j << " \t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

using this code with jave:

```
public void printToken(String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("The tokens of the source code is: \n");
        CharStream inputStream = CharStreams.fromFileName(inputFile);
        TokensLexer tokensLexer = new TokensLexer(inputStream);
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokensLexer);
        tokenStream.fill();
        for (Token token : tokenStream.getTokens()) {
            System.out.println("<" + token.getText() + "> " + "<" + token.getType() + ">");
        }
    }
```

and it gave me the type of each for loop as:

```
<for> <45>
<for> <45>
```

I tried this code:

```
CharStream inputStream = CharStreams.fromFileName(inputFile);
        // lexing the code
        TokensLexer tokensLexer = new TokensLexer(inputStream);
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokensLexer);
        // parsing the code
        TokensParser tokensParser = new TokensParser(tokenStream);
        tokenStream.fill();
        for (Token token : tokenStream.getTokens()) {
            if (token.getType() == 45)
                System.out.println("loop is found");
        }
}
```

When I put "45" it prints out **“loop is found”** twice and when I change the number to "39" it prints out **“loop is found”** only once. 
I tried "39" because I have this value in my generated files from Antlr grammar.

**Tokens.tokens -> for = 45.**

**Tokens.lexer.tokens -> for = 45**

**TokensParser.java -> Rule_forBlock = 39; Rule_forExpression = 40;**

and when I try to add more loops:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            cout << i << j << " \t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int  i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       cout<<"Test"<<endl;
    }    return 0;
}
```

and use the number 39, still detects only one loop.

**Is there a way to detect the loops in the source code using Antlr and differentiate between the outer and inner loop?**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough code/grammar to reproduce what you describe. So I'll give a demo how you could solve it using [the C++ grammar in the ANTLR repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14.g4).

I only changed 1 rule slightly. Instead of:

```
iterationstatement
   : While '(' condition ')' statement
   | Do statement While '(' expression ')' ';'
   | For '(' forinitstatement condition? ';' expression? ')' statement
   | For '(' forrangedeclaration ':' forrangeinitializer ')' statement
   ;
```

I added some [labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) to it:

```
iterationstatement
   : While '(' condition ')' statement                                 #WhileStatement
   | Do statement While '(' expression ')' ';'                         #DoWhileStatement
   | For '(' forinitstatement condition? ';' expression? ')' statement #ClassicForStatement
   | For '(' forrangedeclaration ':' forrangeinitializer ')' statement #ForEachStatement
   ;
```

With these changes, the following demo class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String source = "#include <iostream>\n" +
                "using namespace std;\n" +
                "int main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {\n" +
                "            cout << i << j << \" \\t\";\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "        cout << \"\\n\";\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "    for (int  i = 0; i < 100; i++)\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "       cout<<\"Test\"<<endl;\n" +
                "    }    return 0;\n" +
                "}";

        CPP14Lexer lexer = new CPP14Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
        CPP14Parser parser = new CPP14Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new ForListener(), parser.translationunit());
    }
}

class ForListener extends CPP14BaseListener {

    private int forLevel = 0;

    @Override
    public void enterClassicForStatement(CPP14Parser.ClassicForStatementContext ctx) {
        this.forLevel++;
        printInfo("classic", ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitClassicForStatement(CPP14Parser.ClassicForStatementContext ctx) {
        this.forLevel--;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterForEachStatement(CPP14Parser.ForEachStatementContext ctx) {
        this.forLevel++;
        printInfo("each", ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitForEachStatement(CPP14Parser.ForEachStatementContext ctx) {
        this.forLevel--;
    }

    private void printInfo(String forType, ParserRuleContext ctx) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s for-statement on line %d.%n",
                this.forLevel == 1 ? "OUTER" : "INNER", forType, ctx.getStart().getLine());
    }
}
```

will provide the following output:

```
OUTER classic for-statement on line 5.
INNER classic for-statement on line 7.
OUTER classic for-statement on line 12.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr.Bart. I am sorry for not providing the grammar that I was working with" https://github.com/milderhc/auto-parallelizer" . but now I am using CPP14 after I saw your solution. Can I use "ForEachStatementContext" to know what is the initialization between the parentheses, because I am trying to do dependency analysis for loop statements but I have to know what is the initialization so I can apply dependency analysis tests on them

Comment: "Can I use "ForEachStatementContext" to know what is the initialization between the parentheses", yes, you can.